# Shortcut for creating a list with many repeating Boolean values

Tags: python

If I want to make a list consisting of 12 False Boolean values, is there a shortcut to do this without typing out all 12? I know that `'string ' * 3` returns `'string string string'`. But `True * 3` just returns `3`.

Hopefully this question isn't too simple, but I was having a hard time finding the answer by searching.

Comment: You're close: `[False] * 12`

Comment: not sure why this question got down voted.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to put whatever you're repeating in an array, and then multiply by an integer to get repeating sequence.

`x = [False] * 12` should work.

Comment: Although syntactically valid - the trailling `,` isn't required there (it would if creating a tuple though)